# Coroutine - referencing code in Head First Kotlin (drum machine)

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Hi I would like to know why the sound file only play once when I comment out

```
Thread.sleep(100 * (part.length + 1L))
```

from the code below

```
fun main() {
    playBeats("x-x-x-x-x-x-", "toms.aiff")
}

fun playBeats(beats: String, file: String) {
    val parts = beats.split("x")
    println(parts)
    var count = 0
    for (part in parts) {
        count += part.length + 1
        if (part == "") {
            playSound(file)
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(100 * (part.length + 1L))
            if (count < beats.length) {
                playSound(file)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged kotlin-coroutines? There doesn't seem to be any coroutine here

Comment: As for your question, maybe you cannot play the sound too quickly after already playing one? (you might need to wait until the sound finished playing). What is the `playSound` API that you are using here? Is it from a library? Also, do you get any exceptions when you remove the `Thread.sleep`?